# How to solve failed linking file resources on Android Studio 3 error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I have switched to Android Studio 3. 
After many problems that I fixed, I got these errors:

[image]

[image]

Why, in my layout do I get this error?

When I have commented out `"@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"`, it gets uncommented out again after rebuild.

Above this layout page there is a note:

> Files under build folder are generated and should not be edited

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:text="سامانه پایش همراه"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This is the [complete](http://codepad.org/vVSNkvEY) layout,
and you can see whole Gradle config from [this link](http://codepad.org/ZGqx5hXo).
This is my [Gradle](http://codepad.org/Zdz5U17n) project.

Comment: Instead of down voting , you can help to solve the problem !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see TextAppearance.StatusBar.Even‌​‌​tContent defined In your style : change it into defined style or remove it if it is unacessary

Comment: I delete this line but after rebuild project this line again is added.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html  : paragraph : Incorrect use of @ resource reference symbols

Comment: I think I do important think.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#at_symbol

Comment: I have changed color like this:`<item name="colorPrimary">color/colorPrimary</item>`  but i go this error:`Error:(87, 5) error: expected color but got (raw string) color/gray.`

Comment: can you add color.xml file ?

Comment: Additionally, consider if you incorrectly include the symbol when accessing a resource from the android namespace, as shown below:

...
<!-- When referencing resources from the 'android' namespace, omit the '@' symbol. -->
<item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation"/>
When building the module, AAPT2 now throws the following build error:

Error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have to access to my pc.i will test it tomorrow .why down vote????

Comment: But my main questions was ’android:textAppearance=`@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent`

Comment: I do not know, why I can not change any line of my layout? https://ibb.co/bHuaTG . I got `Design editor is unavailable until a successful build`

Comment: It's not me who downvoted :/ , did you implement the last changes ?

Comment: If your mean is Last change of android studio, yes i do last change. but if your mean is last change of your suggestion, I did not a problem with color, my problem is `’android:textAppearance=@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Even‌​tContent`

Comment: I don't see TextAppearance.StatusBar.Even‌​‌​tContent defined In your style : change it into defined style

Comment: I finally fix it. I have just removed `android:textAppearance=@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Even‌​‌​tContent` in main code and whithout this code, everything is good.

Comment: congrats friend !